# Join a JavaRDD with a JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, join

I've got two files, one with anagrafic data (ID, name, last name) and another one with bank operations (ID, amount, idPerson).

I extracted two JavaRDDs: one regarding the people, another one regarding the total amount of each persons' operations (through a reduceByKey).

How can I create a new `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Subject>` where the Integer is the amount and the Subject is the person?

I tried this but didn't work:

```java
JavaRDD<String> pLines = jsc.textFile("operations.csv").filter(x->!x.contains("ID"));
JavaRDD<String> pLines2 = jsc.textFile("anagraphic.txt").filter(x->!x.contains("\"ID\""));
JavaRDD<Soggetto> pSoggetti = pLines2.map(new EstraiSoggetti());
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> pIDSubjectAmount = pTransazioni.mapToPair((x)->new Tuple2<Integer,Integer>(x.subject, x.amount));
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Transazione> pTransazioni2 = pLines.mapToPair(new EstraiTransazioniPair());
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> pFrequencies2 = pIDSubjectAmount.reduceByKey(new Sum());
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Transazione, Soggetto>> pSoggettiTransazioni = pTransazioni2.join(pSoggetti2);
List<Tuple2<Integer, Soggetto>> list = pSoggetti2.collect();
```

My functions used for extraction

```java
public class EstraiSoggetti implements Function<String, Soggetto> { 
    public Soggetto call(String line) throws Exception { 
        String [] fields = line.split(";"); 
        return new Soggetto(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]), fields[1], fields[2]); 
    } 
}
```

```java
public class EstraiTransazioniPair implements PairFunction<String, Integer, Transazione> { 
    public Tuple2<Integer, Transazione> call(String line) throws Exception { 
         String [] fields = line.split(";"); 
         return new Tuple2<Integer, Transazione>(Integer.parseInt(fields[2]), new Transazione(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]), Integer.parseInt(fields[1]), Integer.parseInt(fields[2]), Integer.parseInt(fields[3]), fields[4])); 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: ` I've tried joins, I tried to reduce but nothing worked.` - please show us how it didn't work

Comment: I tried to create a new `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Subject>` in order to do a join between this new pair and the one I spoke about in the question (`sums`). It wasn't correct

Comment: but why not posting the code? it would be much easier to see what the problem was

Comment: because the code is more complex than I made it. I just asked the question for my problem.

Comment: good luck then, because this is not enough to be able to help you

Comment: I posted the code, can you help me?

Comment: what is `pTransazioni2` and `EstraiSoggetti`? `pLines2.map(new EstraiSoggetti());` looks wrong - maybe should be `pLines2.map((line) -> new EstraiSoggetti(line));` ?

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class EstraiSoggetti implements Function<String, Soggetto> {

 
 public Soggetto call(String line) throws Exception {
  
   if(line.startsWith("\"ID\""))
    return new Soggetto(0, "err","err");
   String [] fields = line.split(";");
   return new Soggetto(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]), fields[1], fields[2]);
  
 }

}
`
This extracts the anagraphic info, creating new Subjects

Comment: still missing how `pLines` is transformed into `pTransazioni2 `

Comment: `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Transazione> pTransazioni2 = pLines.mapToPair(new EstraiTransazioniPair());`

Comment: where EstraiTransazioniPair is

`public class EstraiTransazioniPair implements PairFunction<String, Integer, Transazione> {

 
 public Tuple2<Integer, Transazione> call(String line) throws Exception {
  String [] fields = line.split(";");
  return new Tuple2<Integer, Transazione>(Integer.parseInt(fields[2]), new Transazione(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]), Integer.parseInt(fields[1]), Integer.parseInt(fields[2]), Integer.parseInt(fields[3]), fields[4]));

 }

}`

Comment: Can say what "didn't work" means? Do you get an exception? Or a result that you don't expect?

Comment: I got this exception
java.io.NotSerializableException: gbd.spark.Soggetto

Comment: ... and didn't you think this might be an important information? `Soggetto` has to implement `Serializable`, read the Spark documentation